# What does the "1" in the jest snapshots mean?

Tags: jestjs, snapshot-testing

What does the number 1 in jest snapshots signify?

For example this is a code snippet from their [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing) and I'd like to understand what the number 1 in the first line of code means:

```
// Snapshot
exports[`will fail every time 1`] = `
Object {
  "createdAt": 2018-05-19T23:36:09.816Z,
  "id": 3,
  "name": "LeBron James",
}
`;
```

The number 1 seems to be there in all jest snapshots as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know anything about Jest but it feels the snapshots for `foo` are called `foo 1`, `foo 2`, `foo 3`...